# Why were certain changes made from the stage to movie version of "Sound of Music?'

Tags: screenplay, musical, the-sound-of-music

The [movie version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sound_of_Music_(film)) of the Sound of Music followed the stage version fairly closely. But some meaningful changes were made. Specifically, the movie version added two new songs, "I Have Confidence" and "Something Good," while dropping three songs: "How Can Love Survive, "An Ordinary Couple," and "No Way to Stop It" from the stage version.

The wikipedia link lists these changes, but does not explain why they occurred, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all movies derived from stage musicals will add at least one original song, the objective being to make it eligible for an Academy Award nomination for Best Original Score. In recent memory, *Beauty and the Beast* did this, as did *Les Miserables* and *Into the Woods*. The new *Wicked* movie will have original songs as well. It's actually difficult to find examples of musicals that *didn't* add new songs for the stage version.

Dropping songs is usually done for time. It's not uncommon for stage musicals to clock in at three hours, which is a bit long for a movie version.